# Laravel. получить значение добавлен ли юзер в избранное или нет, (лайкнут или нет)

Tags: php, laravel

Имеются модели:

```
User (id, name)
Favorite (user_id, favorite_id)
```

Как можно при выгрузке коллекции пользователей проверить (отобразить флаг) добавлен ли пользователь в избранное или нет (используют жадную загрузку) ?

Answer (score 0):

В моделях связь ManyToMany:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function favorites()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(App\Favorite::class);
    }
}

class Favorite extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(App\User::class);
    }
}
```

В контроллере получаем количество юзеров с жадной загрузкой Favorites:

```
$users = App\User::withCount('favorites')->get();
```

Во view проверяем количество favorites и выставляем флаг:

```
<ul>
    @foreach ($users as $user)
        <li
            @if ($user->favorites_count > 0)
                class="added-to-favorites"
            @endif
        >{{ $user->name }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```